# Typescript: can't get generics to work with extends

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to restrict input to an object, but it fails:

```
showModal<T extends {[key: string]: any}, U>(component: Type<AbstractDialogComponent<T, U>>,
    options?: ModalDialogOptions & { context: T }): Observable<U> {

    options = { context: {}, viewContainerRef: this.vcRef,
        fullscreen: true , ...options || {} };
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.modal.showModal(component, options));
}
```

The error is: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type T` on the second line.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` can be any type that extends `{[key: string]: any}`, so it could for example be `{ requiredField: number }`. If `T` is this type, the value `{}` is not a valid default for the `T` since `T` has required fields. Thus the compiler disallows the assignment of `{}` since there are calls where it would not be valid.

The usual way to get around this is to use a type assertion :

```
(...options || ({} as T))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I applied that to the context property, and I was able to leave out the `as any` part as well for it to work: `options = { context: ({} as T), ...`

Comment: @BartvandenBurg yeah that should work as well, there were many types missing from the sample (guessing angular) and I didn't runt the code so I went the safer option :)